# Vertical jQuery accordion slider inside tab

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have a really big problem, I based one of my designs around this plugin and now have a mayor issue.

Here is the link to the plugin:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/07/22/vertical-sliding-accordion/

My problem with it is that I was planning to add a content slider inside the slices that will be triggered by the navigation elements inside but when I click on the slice it just closes everything, can anyone figure out a way to just close on clicking the "va-title"?

Also how can I include a slider inside that responds to the navigation elements when clicked, let's say in the ul i have a

Video

so when i click that i load the video content in the same div for every slice?

Thanks and sorry if this sounds like too much trouble.